# How to show a local image in the webview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I want to show a local image in the webview , How to do ? somebody has a easy demo ? thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do is set the baseURL to the Bundles Path. Then from there you can call images from your Bundle like so:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *bundleBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: bundlePath];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL: bundleBaseURL];
```

The Image in your HTML can then call local images directly.

```
<img src="yourImageFromTheMainBundle.jpg" />
```

The same can be used to call CSS files or even JS files because the baseURL looks inside the main Bunble.

If its not in your main bundle, all you have to do is change the baseURL to the path of where the image is located.

Comment: `[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]]` worked for me where the above example did not.

Comment: I may sound bit NOOB, but please tell me where to add this code segment??

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]] worked for me too where as the above example did not

Answer (score 6):

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localImagePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```